# How to pass data in case of success and failure in Scala

Tags: json, scala, jackson

I have developed a code where I am parsing the incoming **`JSON`** data with the predefined format. So, it is working as expected. Now my aim is to send the data to the respective methods `Right` and `Left` which are used by another `Process` Function where I am making `DB` calls.

```
   package KafkaAsSource

import KafkaAsSource.JSONParsingExample.{sampleJsonString, schemaJsonString}
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.{DeserializationFeature, MapperFeature, ObjectMapper}
import com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.{DefaultScalaModule, ScalaObjectMapper}
import com.networknt.schema.{JsonSchemaFactory, SpecVersion}
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.functions.ProcessFunction
import org.apache.flink.util.Collector
import org.apache.flink.api.scala._
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.scala.OutputTag
import scala.jdk.CollectionConverters._
import scala.util.{Failure, Success, Try}

case class Premium(id: String, premium: Long, eventTime: String)

class Splitter extends ProcessFunction[String,Premium] {
  val outputTag = new OutputTag[String]("failed")

  def fromJson[T](json: String)(implicit m: Manifest[T]): Either[String, T] = {
    Try {
      val schema = JsonSchemaFactory.getInstance(SpecVersion.VersionFlag.V4).getSchema(schemaJsonString)
      // You can read a JSON object from String, a file, URL, etc.
      val parsedJson = new ObjectMapper().readTree(sampleJsonString)
      val validationMessages = schema.validate(parsedJson).asScala
      validationMessages.foreach(msg => println(msg.getMessage))
    } match {
      case Success(x) => {
        println(" Good: " + x)
        Right(x)
      }
      case Failure(err) => {
        println("Bad:  " + json)
        Left(json)
      }
    }
  }

  override def processElement(i: String, context: ProcessFunction[String, Premium]#Context, collector: Collector[Premium]): Unit = {
    fromJson(i) match {
      case Right(data) => {
        collector.collect(data)
        println("Good Records: " + data)
      }
      case Left(json) => {
        context.output(outputTag, json)
        println("Bad Records: " + json)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This gives me errors like:

```
type mismatch;
 found   : x.type (with underlying type Unit)
 required: T
        Right(x)
```

In this case, whether the data is correct or not, the `Success` part is always called. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: How (and where) do you check if "the data is correct"?

Comment: `val validationMessages = schema.validate(parsedJson).asScala` this checks whether the data is according to the expected format and the required fields. The last line prints the messages only if the format is not expected.

Comment: So basically it should be like if the `validationMessages` contains any data then call Error part or else success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Try` will only consider something a failure if it throws an exception.  If the block passed to `Try` doesn't throw, it's by definition a `Success`.

So assuming that your `schema.validate(parsedJson)` doesn't throw exceptions but instead returns a collection of validation failures, there are a couple of approaches:

- You can stay in `Try` and throw if there's a failure.  One easy way to accomplish this is with `require`: though it's typically used for expressing preconditions, it's a quick and readable way to throw

```scala
Try {
  // as before
  val validationMessages = schema.validate(parsedJson).asScala

  require(validationMessages.isEmpty)
  parsedJson
} match {
  // as before
}
```

- You can dispense with `Try` (especially if you're sure that none of the other code in that block will throw exceptions) and just go straight to `Either`, with something like:

```scala
val schema = JsonSchemaFactory.getInstance(SpecVersion.VersionFlag.V4).getSchema(schemaJsonString)
// You can read a JSON object from String, a file, URL, etc.
val parsedJson = new ObjectMapper().readTree(sampleJsonString)
val validationMessages = schema.validate(parsedJson).asScala

if (validationMessages.isEmpty) Right(parsedJson)
else Left(json)
```

EDIT: note that in your edited code, where you've added

```scala
validationMessages.foreach(msg => println(msg.getMessage))
```

replacing the `parsedJson` that you had earlier, that changed your `Try` from a `Try[T]` to a `Try[Unit]` which became an `Either[String, Unit]` after the `match`.

Comment: Now it is giving me the error as `type mismatch;
 found   : x.type (with underlying type com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode)
 required: T
        Right(x)
`  when I used your first approach. Do I need to convert the `parsedJson` to JsonNode and then return it?

Comment: I have no idea how in Jackson you would get the desired type out of the parsed JSON.

Comment: desired type here is a JsonNode, right? I know one way of doing it.

Comment: It is an object node. So basically I want to convert object node to JSON node.

Comment: I resolved it. Thanks for your help :)